# Execution of the Custom Redelivery Error Handler is failing when upgraded from Camel 2.x to Camel 3.x

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route in the application as below:

Route 1:

*from(fromUri)
.onException(Throwable.class)
.handled(true)
.end()
.loadBalance(processor_route1)*
*.to(toUri);*

--> processor_route1 in route 1 has the retry/redelivery logic to route 2, in case route 2 has any exceptions
--> toUri direct endpoint

Route 2:

*from(fromUri)*
*.onException(Exception.class)
.handled(true)
.process(responseProcessor)
.end()
.process(processor_route2)
.to(toUri)
.process(responseProcessor)*

--> fromUri: direct endpoint

Recently I upgraded from Camel 2.x to Camel 3.x. In Camel 2.x above route has been working properly. However, in Camel 3.x observing the below error during error case in route 2.

During the first execution, route 2 gets executed completely and returns with an error from toUri (say endpoint1). Control goes to onException block and responseProcessor gets executed.

processor_route1 identifies the error and retries route 2 with a different toUri endpoint for route 2 (say endpoint2). During this execution (first retry attempt), processor_route2 gets executed but the exchange is not forwarded further to endpoint2 and responseProcessor. There are no exceptions also captured, so onException does not get executed. Exchange is returned with success status to processor_route1 which does not get any information about the incomplete route 2 execution.

There have been a lot of changes internal to camel in 3.x version. Can anyone please let me know if there are any changes related to custom redelivery handling or any specific camel property to be considered or used in this scenario?